# Reading Battery Voltage - Alternative to Divider + ADC vs. Gas Gauge IC?

Tags: microcontroller, adc, embedded

I've been through a few design iterations of an 8 bit MCU, using a voltage divider and ADC to display the battery level of a system.  It works okay, but I've found reading battery voltages requires a bit of acrobatics in the software to average and clean and hide any gremlins from the end user as the batteries age and start acting funky.

I'm loosely aware of gas gauge ICs, and what they do -- also how much they cost... not cheap (well compared to a "free" ADC on your MCU + two resistors for the divider network).

Is anyone aware of any alternative ICs or approaches, that cost less than a gas gauge IC but require a bit less development time than an ADC + Voltage Divider? (I'm thinking like ~$0.10).  I'm seeing low cost gas gauge ICs reading voltages and calculating current, so looks like the most recent approach?

I haven't been around embedded systems very long, so maybe there are some older ICs prior to gas gauge ICs that can get the job done? Some different approach?

Comment: You want to read the voltage or the state of charge? These are pretty different.

Comment: Read the voltage, I'll clarify that. (I see Gas Gauge ICs from ST with both functions integrated...).

Comment: Then you really don't need a fuel gauge or a special IC. ADC should work just fine.

Comment: Yeah, it works, there ends up being a bunch of software work to average it out and whatnot.  Curious if anyone handles this outside an MCU's ADC...  I'm not really familiar with the last 40 years worth of ICs, you know? ;)

Comment: @EugeneSh. But reading the OP between the lines so to speak, I think the OP has already been screwing around a lot trying to write lots of code to get the "right output" using only voltage as a means. The problem is that "voltage" by itself is not a good way to go.

Comment: @Leroy105 You will need to collect at least two variables. Perhaps more, even.

Comment: @jonk Well, that's why I asked... Leroy, *why* do you need this voltage?

Comment: @jonk -- tell me about it, voltage is not a great proxy.  Alas, it seems the cheapest.  Wondering if there is a middle-ground to a gas gauge?  Design wise you are throwing in a communication line, vs. monkeying with an ADC.

Comment: So based on the edit you do want the state of charge. Then the gas gauge is the way to go.

Comment: @EugeneSh -- We are inferring the state of charge from the voltage like everyone else using the ADC, you know how fraught with peril that can be.  Question is -- prior to gas gauge ICs how did folks handle this?  Maybe there is a cheaper way than a full out gas gauge IC.

Comment: @Leroy105 If I were doing this kind of project and were tasked to make it "cheaper" than the competing ICs without sacrificing the quality of the output, I'd be spending a lot of time studying exactly what's being asked of me. Partly, this would mean tabulating details about existing gas gauge ICs and what they actually achieve relative to the actual situation with the batteries they are applied to. This would mean buying all of the battery types I wanted to support, all the tools related to those batteries (chargers, etc.) and buying gas gauge ICs, too. And a BIG log book to record results.

Comment: @Leroy105 The voltage is very poor indication of the SOC. Batteries have memory and a very non-linear response. There are many variables the fuel gauge is *trying* to integrate. But even then it is not very accurate.

Comment: @Leroy105 I'd log down as much data as I could, running through various batteries under varying conditions and loads, and I'd record my analyses of all of that. Then I'd go back to my customer and go through the results and insist that they tell me what they want this new gas gauge to achieve relative to the existing approaches and what my cost, size, weight, volume, and other boundaries are. (Some of the data I'd be taking would be battery temperature, load, ambient temperature, current, voltage, and anything else I could think up.)

Comment: @jonk -- Customer "eff'ing work well under all conditions and cost $0.01" ;)

Comment: Older ICs didn't get the job done ... older batteries were less critical about blowing up if mis-handled, and nobody expected accurate gauges.

Comment: @Leroy105 Then, and only then, could I use the eigen values and vectors to decide how to approach this problem as well as or better than the existing ICs (or with as much "slop" as the customer allowed me to get to within the IC performance.)

Comment: @Leroy105 And yeah. I know. Customer always wants 15 digits of *accuracy*, 18 digits of *precision*, and zero need for calibration. Long term drift is 0, variation over ambient temperature is predicted and compensated perfectly, and the initial accuracy is better than the best equipment at NIST. And it literally grows on trees. All they have to do is water them.

Comment: @Jonk -- I've done the voltage logging using a discrete logger (Lascar EL-USB-3) and approximated discharge curves, and the whole thing mostly works... until the battery changes or something is different in the next batch of batteries.  And than you spend a bunch of design time figuring out how to mask that, etc.    It ends up being a lot of time, vs. the cost and lead times on cheap gas gauges are ruthless as well... maybe you old timers have a few tricks up your sleeves?

Comment: @Leroy105 No one does more than they have to. At first, you do what you did. Just measure voltage. Of course, that works "only so well." And if you stick with that method, you will wind up pulling out your hair as competition does you one better -- measure current, too. But that is also the brain-dead approach and obvious. Just compute the energy integral, \$\int V_t\:I_t\:\text{d}t\$. I think this is all that the gas gauge ICs do. (If you know of one that also measures battery temperature, I'd like to see it.) Hard to compete with ICs that do this without sacrificing something.

Comment: @Leroy105 But while the energy integral is a lot better than just voltage, it still only gets you "so far." There are other factors to observe. Action integrals might be one. Temperature another. And so on. If looking for a "cheap way" to approach this, I'd want to find something that someone else hasn't yet considered well. But to do that is a research project. I'm pretty sure something could be figured out. But you need lots of data for that.

Comment: @Leroy105  LiPo fuel gauage IC's are cheap for what they do.  Expensive chargers open charge current every so many minutes to measure Voc to test capacity.  You need to write a decent design spec which is not evident here with your acceptance criteria then see what tradeoffs are need according to your Must and nice to Haves.  I would use Voltage and Current sense with a MOSFET switch to either open load or apply load to estimate SoC in addition to Coulomb counting but we have no idea on your specs vs realistic budget. 10 cents is not realistic. Unless you are producting millions

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 -- Yes, I was looking at a cheap STMicro gas gauge (~$0.40/IC, at 3/K quantities).  I'm sitting around just taking stock of how many design hours, went into massaging an ADC + Voltage Divider.  It's more than I'd like. Seems like a lot going on in there with those gas gauge ICs(ADC + maybe an MCU and a communication device).  What really stinks is lead times -- 38 weeks.  I came across some Taiwanese gas gauge ICs months ago.    I  wouldn't know where to start on design spec criteria -- just trying to discern any alternatives beyond ADC & gas gauge...

Comment: Start with battery voltage and current range from 10% to 100% , mAh max for SoC then accuracy of estimated SoC.  Plenty of stock 1 cell LiPo fuel gauges around. but nothing for SLA.  So again if you cannot choose design specs, you can never have a perfect design that simply meets your test /acceptance criteria and budget.

Comment: Diodes Inc has a 1 cell LiPo battery guage for 0.15ea  1 reel

Comment: Really? I never would think to look at their offerings.  I always see them with just protection ICs.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 -- have you ever touched a simple voltage reset IC?  Takes VDD in, and has a hardwired voltage comparator value (call it 3.3V...), it outputs a signal when the low voltage gets tripped. Typically, you trigger the reset on the MCU so it shuts down...  Saves you from monkeying with ADC readings and voltage divider calcs, costs about $0.06/USD...?  Not really a gas gauge, but you take all that software logic out, tie the output to an MCU input as the low voltage indicator.

Comment: have you ever drained a battery only to find it restored the voltage 10 minutes later?  What is your spec including accuracy ?

Comment: Let me clear. If you cannot define it, no one can design it ( or help you)

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 -- yes, yes I have, but only because I'm hand-wringing over some software...  Not saying it's a perfect solution!  I know where you are coming at.  This kind of thing is tricky because there are engineering requirements and there are in-the-hand-of-user requirements which are unknown.  How much inaccuracy will a user accept, before they call in and say their widget is broken.... that's the real boundary.  Afterwards the engineering requirements are pretty concrete.

Comment: The skill in design engineering comes from experience in knowing how it will fail and verify your assumptions if not sure then quantize the parameters into a spec.

Answer (score 1):

```
1 cell LiPo battery guage $0.15/ea for IC only DS2782

Precision Voltage, Temperature, and Current Measurement System
Accurate Stable Internal Time Base
Absolute and Relative Capacity Estimated from Coulomb Count, Discharge Rate, Temperature and Battery Cell Characteristics
Accurate Warning of Low Battery Conditions
Automatic Backup of Coulomb Count and Age Estimation to Nonvolatile (NV) EEPROM
Gain and Tempco Calibration Allows the Use of Low-Cost Sense Resistors
24-Byte User EEPROM or 16-Byte User EEPROM and Unique 64-Bit ID
Industry 2-Wire Interface with Programmable Slave Address
Tiny 8-Pin TSSOP and 10-TDFN Packages Embed Easily in Thin Prismatic Cell Packs
```